# Label does not print string of imported DLL function

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I have created a DLL in c++ contain a function that simply return string "Hello". However, when I import this dll in c# application and try to show this output in label, it displays nothing

Here is my code

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    { 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close(); 
        }
        [DllImport("Dll1.dll", EntryPoint = "Print_Hello", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

        public static extern string Print_Hello();
        private void click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = Print_Hello();
            Hllolbl.Text = s;
        } 
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Help us to help you. Please remove all the irrelevant parts of this code. That's the 'minimal' part of [MCVE]. I'm going to suggest an edit which leaves just 7 lines from your 44.

Comment: did you tried debugging ? if yes, you mean `Print_Hello()` returns empty ?

Comment: yes it returns null